# Are 2013 (not 2010) Reusable Workflows allowed to use Assign A Task action?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow2013, dashboard-designer-2013, reusable-workflow

I would like to make a reusable 2013 workflow that can assign an approval task. The Assign A Task action is not available in Sharepoint Designer 2013 and the Workflow Tasks list setting is not available on the properties page for a reusable workflow. Is this by design?
I do see Assign a Task for 2013 list workflows and I see the Workflow Tasks setting, as well. I have configured my SharePoint environment for App Permissions and granted them (using the guid permission) to Workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this issue occur on all sites or just one site? In my testing, I could use "Assign a task" action in a SharePoint 2013 reusable workflow, and set its properties.
[image]

Did you use App Step for this action? Please try to add it just into a **Stage** and compare the result.

You can try it on different sites and compare the result.

In addition, please provide a screenshot about **Action** when clicking it.

Comment: Interestingly, when I went back into SPD after making the List Workflow and using the Assign A Task action, it then reappeared for the Reusable Workflow. I don't know if something had to come down from the server or get registered somehow, somewhere but it all seems to be working now. Thank you!